# When to use ViewStub vs Inflate?

Tags: android, viewstub

The article http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-with.html talks well about when to use View.
But I did not find a use case where I should replace the Inflate with ViewStub.
I didnot see any performance improvements when I replaced inflate with ViewStub.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to correct errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially ViewStubs just offer another way of doing things, or "achieving your goal". I find that you'll learn to use them when you are stuck and looking for help or another option. Otherwise if your code is doing what you want correctly without ViewStubs, then just forget about them for the time being.
There is no point forcing yourself to use extra options when you don't need them.

ViewStubs, in my own words, are "use once", temporary type of view holder. Use them when you want something to become visible on the screen only for that Activity's current life cycle.

There are other way you can accomplish that, but ViewStubs are very lightweights and simply offer a slightly different set of pros and cons compared to normal View objects.